# c++ headers like cstdio or cstdlib raise compilation errors

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, std

The following code raises many errors:

```
namespace ns1 {
     #include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>
     ...
}
```

> /usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdlib:118: error: '::div_t' has not been
>   declared    using ::div_t;
>              ^
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.9/cstdlib:119: error: '::ldiv_t' has not been
>   declared    using ::ldiv_t;
>              ^

As far as I understand the error cstdlib is in a namespace but stdlib.h is not (which is included from cstdlib and used for most definitions).

What technical solutions allow me to keep the inclusion under a custom namespace and resolve any collisions?

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose the problem with this little information. Do you have some source to show and/or a compilation command?

Comment: Are these the only kind of error? How about not found header files? Looks a bit like the compiler is unable to find the standard C headers. Please do also format the posted error codes the same as they're shown to you by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem - inclusion was within a namespace

Comment: As there is no code in your question, this answer will not help people making the same mistake. I suggest you improve your question including the not working code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually errors like this are caused by something you included before it.

Check for classes or structs defined without a semi-colon after the closing brace.